# IIS 7 Extremely slow for .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7

I'm running IIS7 on Server 2008 (R1).  When I run a completely blank .aspx page, the page still takes more than one second to load, even after compiling and refreshing the browser several times.

A non-aspx file, i.e. image or css file takes about 200ms.  I've even timed it from the BeginRequest event to the EndRequest event, which reports that it takes 15ms.  However, in the IIS logs, it reports that the total request time was about 1.1 seconds.

So there is >1 second of processing time which is being taken by IIS internal code, which has nothing to do with my code.  Any idea what in the IIS code itself could be taking this long?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling localhost? Are you using FireFox?

Comment: @Philippe: I've only heard of Firefox slowness with the broken integrated development server in VS, not with IIS. Also the delay wouldn't show up in the IIS logs.

Comment: Never mind, this was something dumb on my part and is now fixed.  Can we just delete this question?

Comment: @nganju: what did you do to solve it? Instead of asking to delete the question it's way better towards a community to solved your own question. Others might suffer the same mistake and find a valuable answer here in the future.

Comment: My answer is not that useful.  Like I said, the code I was using to time the request reported that it took 200ms.  But this code took 900ms to write that result to a file, because of the way that the logger was written.  Like I said, pretty dumb on my part :)

Comment: I think you've wrote Thread.Sleep(900-200) :)))))